# Pause animation when mousemove event occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(source)
.on('mouseenter', start)
.on('mouseleave', stop)
.on('mousemove', zoom.move);
```

Here I attach few mouse event listeners. When 'mouseenter' event occurs, the following function is executed:

```
    automove: function myAutomove() {

        var xPos = rand(0, outerWidth);
        var yPos = rand(0, outerHeight);

        $(img).animate({
            'top': (yPos - offset.top) * -yRatio + 'px',
            'left': (xPos - offset.left) * -xRatio + 'px' 
        }, defaults.speed, myAutomove);

    }
```

It works great for now, but when 'mousemove' event occurs, the following is executed:

```
    move: function (e) {

        var left = (e.pageX - offset.left),
        top = (e.pageY - offset.top);

        top = Math.max(Math.min(top, outerHeight), 0);
        left = Math.max(Math.min(left, outerWidth), 0);

        img.style.left = (left * -xRatio) + 'px';
        img.style.top = (top * -yRatio) + 'px';

    },
```

The problem is that when mousemove event occurs I should clear animation queue, but there I have transition animation that needs to complete first. These both effects are applied to the same element, so if I simple write the following:

```
$img.clearQueue().stop();
```

... transition animation is not displayed.

You can see live example in the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SL8t7/

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here.  Do you want the move animation to wait until the the transition is complete before stopping the other animations?

Comment: I want when mousemove event occurs, wait for one animation to complete and delete another animation from animation queue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend adding the onmousemove listener to the animation set in the "start" method.
Also, I would remove the onmousemove listener when the "stop" method fires.

That way mousemove only ever gets triggered after the transition is complete.

Here is a jsfiddle with the changes I've proposed

http://jsfiddle.net/XrKna/1/

You'll see that the move event waits for the transition to finish now.

I moved the event binding from here...

```
                $(source)
                .on('mouseenter', start)
                .on('mouseleave', stop);
```

to here

```
                function start() {
                    zoom.init();
                    $img.stop().
                    fadeTo($.support.opacity ? settings.duration : 0, 1, function(){$img.on('mousemove', zoom.move)});
                    zoom.automove();
                }

                function stop() {
                    $img.off('mousemove', zoom.move);
                    $img.clearQueue().stop()                    
                    .fadeTo(settings.duration, 0);
                    manual_step = 0;
                }
```

Comment: Thank you! Today is one of these days when I cannot sort out my thoughts... works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom queues. For example:

```
$(img).animate({
  // properties
},
{
  duration: defaults.speed,
  complete: myAutomove,
  queue: 'autoMove' // here we attached this animation to a custom queue named 'autoMove'
}.dequeue('autoMove'); // for custom queues we have to start them manually
```

If you want to stop the animations in a custom queue just call:

```
$(img).stop('autoMove', true); // the 'true' ensures the custom queue is cleared as well as stopped
```

I didn't really follow which animation you were trying to stop and which you were allowing to continue so I have not updated your jsFiddle, but I think you get the idea.